# Anybody else using MonoDevelop?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mono, monodevelop

I'm starting a new project in MonoDevelop, and I want to see how other projects are using it.

I tried searching through SourceForge, code.google.com, etc., but mostly I was just finding things like add ins or something related to MonoDevelop itself.

So is there anyone else using MonoDevelop, especially open source?

Comment: @OP: Discussion "questions" like this should be community wikis. You can go back and make this one by clicking edit, and then ticking the community wiki checkbox and clicking save.

Comment: @"belongs on superuser" voters: Programming tools aren't programming-related?!

Comment: Yes yes yes I am. But only for linux apps. I still use the (excellent) Visual Studio on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, MonoDevelop is designed to function very similar to Visual Studio, including using all the same sln/proj file types.  You can take a VS solution, open it in MD, and hit F5 to run it, and vice versa.

Because of this, I don't know that many people are going to write about "how they use MD as part of their project" any more than someone is going to write about how they use Notepad.

Any project that is using sln/proj files on Linux/Mac is likely using MD.

Comment: At the present moment MonoDevelop worse than Visual Studio. In VS I at least can install VsVim, or even integrate it. The isn't true with MD. Also it doesn't have an option to add an arguments to launch an application — what a horroble omission.

Comment: But on the other side MonoDevelop have a vertical guides, and have no this horroble blue-green mud color scheme :D

Answer (score 1):

MonoDevelop is multiplatform IDE, especially for Linux. Works with Visual Studio solution and project files (100% both direction compatibility). So you can't find project using it. Any C#/VB.NET project can be developed in MD.

Comment: You're missing the point of my question.  I just wanted to know how others are using MonoDevelop as part of their project, and their experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

Three years ago me and a friend started work a new mono project and tried to use MonoDevelop for it. However - this was an impossible mission - we got ridden with all kinds of bugs and crashes and in the end I said - go to hell MonoDevelop - I'll use my tried and true Emacs.

To tell you the truth with no features other than formatting and font locking Emacs turned out to be 10 times more productive environment for me. My friend somehow endured using MonoDevelop for the whole run of the project, but afterwards he said he was done with Linux for good if it offered such low quality dev tools.

Times were different back then, I've been following mono's development and monodevelop's as well - they seem to be turning out quite well. I think that the actual cause of your problem - not finding anything - lies in the fact that most Linux devs openly shun Mono as a development platform because of it's Microsoft roots. This is sad - because it's a solid alternative of Java - especially at the desktop applications front(GTK# is seriously cool).

[Banshee](http://banshee-project.org/contribute/write-code/) seems to be using MonoDevelop. Probably most of the prominent mono projects with a GUI use it as well to some extent.

Comment: I can't speak for MD, but I have come to find that If I come back to a piece of software 6-12 months later on Linux, it's usually improved upon itself quite a bit.

Comment: I think it is a shame too, although, to be quite honest, I avoided it for a long time as well for the same reason.  I just eventually came to the realization that a good tool is a good tool, even if it has ties to Microsoft.  Thanks for the tip about banshee.

Answer (score 0):

I've found MonoDevelop to be excellent so far. I've only been using it for about a month, but once I got it set-up the way I want it, I wouldn't go back to any other editor or IDE on Linux. It took me a while to figure out how to set the debugger up and configure the editor to how I like it.

It's almost like having Visual C# Express on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for MonoTouch projects. Mac + MonoDevelop + .NET iPhone apps.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried compiling my project, 2 problems:

- couldn't load Setup projects
- couldn't load SQL Server Library projects

There is a way around this of course, just have to consider that not all project types can be built in mono and must design solution the way it doesn't stop you from building what you want.